# how to write polynomial fractions as sum or difference of other fractions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example I have the fraction $$q(n) = \frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2} = \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

My question is how do you find those differences/sums of separated fractions ?

Comment: Google "Partial fractions"

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When factorizing the denominator, you find
$$q(n) = \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2n^2}$$
Now, for separating into two different fractions
$$q(n) = \frac{an+b}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{cn+d}{n^2}$$
In general, the order of the polynomial in the numerator has to be equal to the order of the polynomial in the denominator $-1$. Summing both fractions
$$q(n) = \frac{(an+b)n^2+(cn+d)(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2n^2}=\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2n^2}$$
Then, you have an equality between two polynomials
$$(an+b)n^2+(cn+d)(n+1)^2=2n+1$$
which leads to four independent equations for the 4 variables
$$\mbox{for}\; n^3:a+c=0\\
\mbox{for}\; n^2:b+2c+d=0\\
\mbox{for}\; n:c+2d=2\\
\mbox{for}\; n^0:d=1$$
which leads to your solution